# Overriding the border for required inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I simply want to override the border or outline color that the browser uses on a required field when it detects that the field has been left empty.
I have tried supplying a different border-color to `input:required:invalid {...}` but the css seems to apply straight away when the page loads.

[image: screenshot]

So instead, I've created an `.invalid` class which I want to add to any input that triggers an 'invalid' event via jquery. I just don't know how to get it to wrok. This is what I have so far:

*(`input.bind` throws an Uncaught TypeError (input.bind is not a function) but not sure what to put instead..)*

```
 let inputs = $('input, select');
 inputs.each(function (input) {
     input.bind("invalid", function () {
        input.addClass("invalid");
     });

     input.bind("input", function () {
        if (input.validity.valid) {
           input.removeClass('invalid');
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Browsers don't apply any `:invalid` styling by default. If some is being applied to your `input` elements, then it must be being applied by your code, somewhere. With regard to `bind()`, that's deprecated and should be changed to `on()`

Comment: Rory, thanks for your response. I'm really at loss here becasue I cannot find any such style when I inspect the page so do not know what is causing it. Hence I assumed the browser. Also I get the same Uncaught TypeError when I use .on ("input.on is not a function")

Comment: Actually, I believe this is just a default style with Firefox

Comment: The 'input.on is not a function' error is because you're using the first argument of the `each()` handler - that's the index. The element reference is the second argument, so change it to `function(i, input) {...`. That being said, the loop isn't necessary at all. You can just bind the event handlers directly to the `$('input, select')` selector, jQuery will apply it to all selected elements for you

Comment: Great, that makes sense. I'll give it a go!

Comment: You're right, the border is added in Firefox! I've added an answer for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red border around the `input` is only added when they are in an invalid state, and only in Firefox. To remove this you can apply the following CSS to the element:

```css
input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

With regard to your jQuery code, the first argument to the `each()` handler function is the *index* of the current element in the collection, not a reference to the element itself. As such the code should be:

```
inputs.each(function(i, input) {
```

That being said, the `each()` loop itself is redundant as jQuery will apply the event handlers to all elements in the collection when you call the relevant method. The code can be simplified to just this:

```js
$('input, select').on({
  invalid: e => $(e.target).addClass('invalid'),
  input: e => $(e.target).toggleClass('invalid', e.target.validity.valid)
});
```

Comment: This does the trick! Thanks Rory. There is one other annoying event that this does not capture, and that is when the input filed is focused/visited but then clicked away from with no input provided. Any clue as to what that event is in JS?

Comment: You could use the `blur` event for that, to check if the value is empty